# SAPGUI Script that used to work is giving me Run time error'91': object variable or with block variable not set**

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, sap-gui

I wrote a script on excel vba for SAP GUI and used to work fined but currently I'm getting

> **Run time error'91': object variable or with block variable not set**

This error happens on the below bolded set objConn = objgui.children(0) line.

I always have the page logon to proceed but its keep giving me error.
Additionally, the scripting function does not work on SAP either. It used to work but not anymore. When I record it and play it back it says it can't find the file.

Scripting is enabled. I can press the red record button and finish record by yellow square button but nothing is getting recorded and no files are saved. However, it says:

> SAP frontend server: Scripting support is disabled on the server

```
Option Explicit
Public SapGuiAuto
Public objGui As GuiApplication
Public objConn As GuiConnection
Public session As GuiSession


Sub dd()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim lastrow As Long

    Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
    Set objGui = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
    # Set objConn = objGui.Children(0)
    Set session = objConn.Children(0)
    
    lastrow = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Define where is last row
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    For i = 2 To lastrow 'Row 2 to lastrow will be inputted      
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1) = "Z2" Then
            session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "niw21" 'Input niw21 t-code in SAP
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

I tried remove and install the SAP Logon 770.
I made sure the reference is added on the VBA (SAP GUI Scripting API).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Run-Time error '91' when trying to connect to SAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64364514/getting-run-time-error-91-when-trying-to-connect-to-sap)

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that you have installed your SAP GUI software with the component "SAP GUI Scripting" selected, otherwise you can't use SAP GUI Scripting from your laptop.

NB: to enable Server-Side Scripting (source: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49073813/enabling-sap-mode-for-sap-logon-pad-in-blue-prism)):

- Start the SAP Logon and log in to the SAP server.
- Run the ‘RZ11’ transaction (type ‘RZ11 ‘and click the green tick button)
- Type ‘sapgui/user_scripting’ in the Maintain Profile Parameters window.
- Click the ‘Display’ button
- Click ‘Change Value’ in the Display Profile Parameter Attributes window.
- Type ‘TRUE’ in the ‘New value’ field.
- Save the settings and log out from SAP Logon.
- Exit from the SAP Logon program (click the red cross button in the toolbar, or click the ‘X’ window button to close the window and the application). You may be prompted to save any unsaved changes, if you haven’t done so already.

If you're not authorized, please ask the SAP system administrator.